# In WIN 8 DP- How to set output audio device to speaker instead of USB using powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-8, powershell-3.0

I have gone through many of the forums "To set output audio device to speaker instead of USB" in Windows 8 DP. but i could not find any solution how to do this using powershell. can some one help me in this ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to script changing your audio output device. You can do this via the registry. See this blog post for a script that does this:

http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2008/12/switching-audio-input-and-output-with-powershell/

This may not invoke a change immediately like the applet does. For that you might have to invoke the API and it doesn't look like it's easy.

Someone made a little command line program implemented in C++ you can download the source and binary here:

http://www.daveamenta.com/2011-05/programmatically-or-command-line-change-the-default-sound-playback-device-in-windows-7/

It didn't run on my Windows 7 system but that may be because I don't have the correct Visual C++ redistribute installed. You might try this version if you get an error running it.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=29

Comment: thanks Andy, i have already gone through these links. but i am looking for a single cmdlt from powershell only on Windows 8 developer preview. please help me in this regard.

Comment: @jakkpraveen There is no cmdlet to do this unfortunately. You can review the full cmdlet list in the Windows 8 developer preview [here](http://andyarismendi.blogspot.com/2011/09/new-commands-in-powershell-v3-from.html).

Comment: good stuff Andy.. can you help me in how to get my requirement done using powershell scripts?

Comment: there is no registry key available in windows 8 for $regKey = $regRoot + "\Multimedia\Sound Mapper\"

Comment: @jakkpraveen I haven't had a chance to boot up my Windows dev preview... What I would do is use a reg diff tool such as [this one](http://code.google.com/p/regshot/updates/list) and capture changes, make a change with the audio applet, recapture and compare the results. This will give you an idea of how to manipulate the settings in the registry.